# How to run a mediation analysis in Stata for the model specified below?

Tags: mediation

I'm running a regression model with a binary independent variable X (3 treatment groups, three dummies, 2 dummies included in the regression and the third as reference category) on a continuous dependent variable Y. I have hypothesised a mediation effect via an ordinal mediator M (Likert scale). Which package for mediation analysis in Stata should I install? I'm new to this, so I'm happy to hear an explanation as detailed as you could give . Thank you in advance!